# Asp.Net accessing Claims Identity in an external assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, claims

I'm implementing an Asp.Net WebApi application, where I'm storing some user specific values in claims.

My project consist of several class library projects, where it has models and controllers.

Now I'm trying to access the claims apart from the main project (in a class library) controller.

```
//calling this from a class library
var identity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity; //No user information such as Id available
var claims = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims; //Contains zero elements
```

Here the claims contains zero elements. But if I put above code in a controller of main project everything works fine.

How can I access the claims from an external assembly?

Comment: It would be probably a better idea to just *pass* the identity, instead of relying on some static member you cannot control. Makes your libraries testable too.

Comment: @poke I was able to access identity object using `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity;' but I cannot see user information on it. Could you please provide an answer with simple example?

Comment: In your web API, simply call your library like this: `myCustomLibrary.DoSomething(currentPrincipal, otherArgument)` – i.e. pass the principal to your methods.

Comment: Simply I need to read the claims inside class library's controller method. So somehow i need to access `CurrentPrincipal` object. So I don't think i can use your suggestion. Is it Ok If i call `MainAssembly.GetCurrentPrincipal()` ? Is it a good practice? Or any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

After some investigation I removed  `SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();`from startup configuration class.
Now `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity` works as expected.